# Extending Eclipse generic text editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to implement the `IContentAssistProcessor` Interface to extend an eclipse plugin with the help of the generic editor template recently provided by the last versions of Eclipse. I can't run Auto completion as I would like to. So far, when I run the target Eclipse platform and I perform an auto completion in my text (In my case is by pressing `CTRL + Space` after a letter) I unfold a menu, I autocomplete my text and it works well so far but the next time I unfold this menu the list misses the last item chosen just before. How can I change this program to keep a complete list of item unfolding all the time? the code is:

```
public class DbdContentAssistProcessor implements IContentAssistProcessor {

    public static final String[] PROPOSALS = new String[] { 
        "ield(NAME,", 
        "ield(DESC,", 
        "ield(ASG,", 
        "ield(SCAN,", 
        "ield(PHAS,",
        "ield(PINI,",
        "ield(SDIS," };

    public static final String[] PROPOSALS1 = new String[] { 
        "ecord(ai, ", 
        "ecord(bi, ", 
        "ecord(calcout, ", 
        "ecord(longin, ", 
        "ecord(longout, ", 
        "ecord(string in, ",
        "ecord(string out, ", 
        "ecord(lsi, ", 
        "ecord(lso, ", 
        "ecord(waveform, ", 
        "ecord(bi, ", 
        "ecord(bo, ",            
    };  

    @Override
    public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int offset) { 
        String text = viewer.getDocument().get();

        String natureTag= "f";
        String projectReferenceTag="r";
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

        if (text.length() >= natureTag.length() && text.substring(offset - natureTag.length(), offset).equals(natureTag)) {
            IProjectNatureDescriptor[] natureDescriptors= workspace.getNatureDescriptors();
            ICompletionProposal[] proposals = new ICompletionProposal[natureDescriptors.length];
            for (int i= 0; i < natureDescriptors.length; i++) {
                IProjectNatureDescriptor descriptor= natureDescriptors[i];
                proposals[i] = new CompletionProposal(descriptor.getNatureId(), offset, 0, descriptor.getNatureId().length());
            }

            return Arrays.asList(PROPOSALS).stream().filter(proposal -> !viewer.getDocument().get().contains(proposal))
                .map(proposal -> new CompletionProposal(proposal, offset, 0, proposal.length()))
                .toArray(ICompletionProposal[]::new);
        }

        if (text.length() >= projectReferenceTag.length() && text.substring(offset - projectReferenceTag.length(), offset).equals(projectReferenceTag)) {
            IProjectNatureDescriptor[] natureDescriptors= workspace.getNatureDescriptors();
            ICompletionProposal[] proposals1 = new ICompletionProposal[natureDescriptors.length];
            for (int i= 0; i < natureDescriptors.length; i++) {
                IProjectNatureDescriptor descriptor1= natureDescriptors[i];
                proposals1[i] = new CompletionProposal(descriptor1.getNatureId(), offset, 0, descriptor1.getNatureId().length());
            }

            return Arrays.asList(PROPOSALS1).stream().filter(proposal -> !viewer.getDocument().get().contains(proposal))
                .map(proposal1 -> new CompletionProposal(proposal1, offset, 0, proposal1.length()))
                .toArray(ICompletionProposal[]::new);
        }
        return new ICompletionProposal[0];
    }

    @Override
    public IContextInformation[] computeContextInformation(ITextViewer viewer, int offset) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
        return new char[] { '¨'  }; 

    @Override
    public char[] getContextInformationAutoActivationCharacters() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IContextInformationValidator getContextInformationValidator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```